# Post data with Angular JS from HTML form. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, post

I'm trying to post a form with inputs to my PHP backend by using Angular JS. The PHP backend is fine I tested it with POSTMAN.

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=valForm&p1=Error%3…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="valForm">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customersStyle.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div  ng-controller="valController">
      <form>
        <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder='Name' >
        <input name="surname" ng-model="surname" type="text" id="surname" placeholder='Surname'>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="submit()" value="SUBMIT"></input>
      </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Angular JS code the I changed the link to valid_link on purpose:

```
(function(){
     angular.module('valForm', [])
     .controller('valController',function($scope, $http){   
            $scope.submit = function(){
                $http({
                    method:'POST',url:"valid_link", 
                    params: {
                        name:$scope.name,
                        surname:$scope.surname
                    }   
                })  
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.result = response;
                    console.log(result);
                    })
                .error(function(){
                    console.log("error");
                });
            };
        });
    })();
```

Comment: you have to specify ng-model for the input field. Then only the $scope will fetch the data

Comment: @Thinker I added them but the error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] is still there

Comment: You may remove the encapsulation around your module definition, it is unnecessary.

Comment: @victor175 I removed the encapsulation but its still not working

Comment: Try moving your javascript requests to the bottom of the body, also where exactly do you attach the javascript code you include to this page?

Comment: @victor175 I wasnt even adding the Javascript anywhere to the HTML.  thank you, may you add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the custom javascript code was never referenced in the page.

Should add this in the bottom of the body:

```
<script src="mycode.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must specify ng-model for every input field in your form. Just change it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="valController">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="data.name" placeholder='Name' />
    <input name="surname" type="text" ng-model="data.surname" placeholder='Surname' />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and **JS CODE** :

```
angular.module('valForm', [])
 .controller('valController',function($scope, $http){   
        $scope.data = {};
        var param = function(data) {
              var returnString = '';
              for (d in data){
                  if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
                     returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
              }
              return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
        };
        $scope.submit = function(){
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:"valid_link", 
                data : param($scope.data)
            })
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.result = response;
                console.log(result);
                })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
        };
     });
```

This might help you :)

Comment: I added them but the error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] is still there